# Error with JScrollPane and Content

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I couldn't explain the question in the title any better, so here goes -

I created a tiled background image. I then set the created  background image to my JFrame. However, I added my JScrollPane to said background. Depending on the order I place my code in, 1 of two things will happen. When I have my JScrollPane like so -

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestingApp {

public static JFrame programFrame;
public static JLabel projectBackground;
public static JLabel projectLogo;
public static JPanel allContent;
public static JPanel fourRows;
public static JPanel centerPanel;
public static JScrollPane scrollPane;

// Tiled Background
public static void tiledBackground() {

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
        public Image image;
        public boolean tile;

        ImagePanel(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
            this.tile = true;
        };

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int iw = image.getWidth(this);
            int ih = image.getHeight(this);
            if (iw > 0 && ih > 0) {
                for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += iw) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += ih) {
                        g.drawImage(image, x, y, iw, ih, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Making the parts for the GUI
public static void createGUI() {
    java.net.URL img1 = null;
    try {
        img1 = new URL("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSE6uHn-B_qKtLZOKjQNVeIxhOaxbmfio45VMUq-mVgGKvgmeghKw");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Image image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(img1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // programFrame Title and Layout
    programFrame = new JFrame("Organizer");
    programFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    Icon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(img1);
    projectBackground = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);

    // Logo JLabel
    java.net.URL img2 = null;
    try {
        img2 = new URL("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvXxBQRsJ5NgSb8VOSNU_Qfom6HRV_crcazhD6bSZUh_ux3VHbgQ");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Icon logoIcon = new ImageIcon(img2);
    projectLogo = new JLabel(logoIcon);
    projectLogo.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

    // New JPanel for GridLayouts to hold each JPanel with GridLayouts
    fourRows = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 4));
    fourRows.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    fourRows.setOpaque(false);
    fourRows.add(new JButton("Button"));
    fourRows.add(new JButton("Button"));
    fourRows.add(new JButton("Button"));
    fourRows.add(new JButton("Button"));

    // Makes the Initial BorderLayout (Using allContent JPanel)
    allContent = new JPanel();
    allContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    allContent.add(projectLogo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    allContent.setVisible(true);
    allContent.setOpaque(false);
    allContent.add(fourRows, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // Add ScrollPane
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(allContent);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
    scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
    scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

    // JFrame programFrame Constructors
    programFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    programFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    programFrame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(image));
    programFrame.add(scrollPane);

    programFrame.pack();
    programFrame.setVisible(true);
    programFrame.setResizable(true);
    programFrame.setSize(1280, 720);
    programFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

} // public static void createGUI() Closing

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createGUI();

        } // public void run() Closing
    });
}
}
```

It doesn't scroll on the entire JFrame, just the contentStuff, and even then, it stretches beyond to the bottom of the content to where the scroll bar isn't there, and you can't scroll.

However, when I rearrange that code, and I put my

```
programFrame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(image));
```

BEFORE

```
programFrame.add(scrollPane);
```

I just get the repeated background image, and no content.

EDIT - Added an SSCCE

EDIT2 - Here's a solution I was trying. I tried creating an empty panel to add in the content that should update based on JFrame size. Needless to say, it didn't work. Small snippet of the edited code, nothing else was changed -

```
// Makes the Initial BorderLayout (Using allContent JPanel)
allContent = new JPanel();
allContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
allContent.add(warlordsLogo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
allContent.setVisible(true);
allContent.setOpaque(false);
allContent.add(fourRows, BorderLayout.CENTER);

int widthForCenterPanel = programFrame.getWidth();
int heightForCenterPanel = programFrame.getHeight();

// Makes a Panel to add the ScrollPane to to center is properly
centerPanel = new JPanel();
centerPanel.setOpaque(false);
centerPanel.setBounds(0, 0, widthForCenterPanel, heightForCenterPanel);
centerPanel.add(allContent);

// Add ScrollPane
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(centerPanel);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
scrollPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

EDIT 3 - Fixed my SSCCE. If you notice when you try it, it's dependent on how large the JPanel is, not the JFrame.

Comment: Just FYI, SSCCE means Short, Self Contained, Correct Example. Not necessarily code from your project but something that reproduces the problem and people can take it and run it.

Comment: Yeah, I meant, in my post, that posting a self contained example wouldn't really be plausible.

Comment: Why not plausible? Too much effort? The structure of your program has little bearing on an sscce.

Comment: *"I broke up my program into multiple class files"*  An SSCCE can have more than one class, but only one `public` class.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That's certainly NOT the case. If other people would be willing to take time to help me, of course I'd be willing to go through the effort of posting an SSCCE. I'm not sure how to actually do that without having many undefined methods, but if I get time today, I'll try and do it.

Comment: If you have time, then definitely try to create one. I don't know about others, but to begin to approach your problem, I would have to create an SSCCE first, and so it would be far better if you did this yourself for the benefit of all of us. Good luck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry for the incredibly long wait, I was really busy the past few weeks. I added an SSCCE, after I tried to fix it myself.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I added something I tried, which didn't work. May you take a look at it? (It has an SSCCE this time.)

Comment: Where is your [sscce](http://sscce.org)? I can't compile or run any of the code you've posted so I don't see anything above that qualifies.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Should be fixed this time. I can compile and run this.